# Not Jailbroken - getting Provisioning is not applicable for product type 'Application' in SDK Device

Tags: iphone, xcode, certificate, keychain, codesign

Codesign warning: provisioning is not applicable for product type 'Application'  in SDK Device - iPhone OS3.1'; ignoring..

Redownloaded my developer certificate, made a new provisioning profile, still getting this error. Searched the Xcode project and removed all lines referencing a Provisioning Profile, but that didn't seem to remove it from the project settings (went to show package contents, then opened the project file).

Was originally on a different machine then transferred over, if that makes a difference?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the file

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Info.plist
```

and make sure the following keys are set to YES

```
<key>PROVISIONING_PROFILE_ALLOWED</key>
<string>YES</string>
<key>PROVISIONING_PROFILE_REQUIRED</key>
<string>YES</string>
```

When developing for a jailbroken devices, these should normally be set to NO, so you can self sign and copy the file over, etc, but it's not necessary to skip this when you actually have a proper certificate and provisioning for your device.

Comment: It's been ages; your answer looks reasonable. Cheers.